# What is reincarnated?

Tags: reincarnation

What is reincarnated? Does reincarnation occur in the realm of conventional reality?

Well I had to put in some superfluous words because the website wouldn't accept just a simple question.

Comment: Hi. I'm pretty sure this question has been asked and answered -- please review some of the [topics tagged '**rebirth**'](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rebirth) as well as [topics tagged '**reincarnation**'](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reincarnation). There are so many in the past that it's hard to choose which one this question is a duplicate of!!

Answer (score 1):

It appears original Buddhism did not teach about "reincarnation". It appears "reincarnation" was introduced into Buddhism at a later time.

The Pali suttas show original Buddhism taught about **"upapajjati" ("re-arising")**, which means a certain result arising following from certain actions. "Upapajjati" is concerned with the results of kamma or morality.

The original Pali suttas most often say what is "re-arises" is the former sense of "being" or "self".

For example, you have the idea: "*I will rob this bank because I want to have money*". Then when you are imprisoned for robbing the bank, you have the painful regret: "*Why was I so stupid to get get caught?*". What "re-arises" is the same sense of "being", "self" or "I"; that is caught up or strongly attached to the idea of robbing a bank for money.

The scriptures say:

> 'These **beings** — who were endowed with bad conduct of body, speech &
>   mind, who reviled noble ones, held wrong views and undertook actions
>   under the influence of wrong views — with the break-up of the body,
>   after death, have re-appeared in the plane of deprivation, the bad
>   destination, the lower realms, in hell. But these **beings** — who were
>   endowed with good conduct of body, speech & mind, who did not revile
>   noble ones, who held right views and undertook actions under the
>   influence of right views — with the break-up of the body, after death,
>   have re-appeared in the good destinations, in the heavenly world.'

Therefore what "re-arises" is "a being". The scriptures also say "a being" is a mental state of strong attachment, as follows:

> 'A being,' lord. 'A being,' it's said. To what extent is one said to
>   be 'a being'?"
>
> "Any desire, passion, delight, or craving for form, Radha: when one is
>   caught up there, tied up there, one is said to be 'a being.'
>
> "Any desire, passion, delight, or craving for feeling... perception...
>   fabrications...
>
> "Any desire, passion, delight, or craving for consciousness, Radha:
>   when one is caught up there, tied up there, one is said to be 'a
>   being.'
>
> [SN 23.2](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn23/sn23.002.than.html)

While "a being" is a mental state of delusion; it is this delusion that "re-arises" or "upapajjati".

Comment: There are further details about *upapajjati* in e.g. [this topic](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/29355/254), if you'd like to reference that.