# What did the Buddha mean in AN 5.38 with the fifth benefit to a person of faith?

Tags: theravada, pali-canon, sutras, faith

What did the Buddha mean in [AN 5.38.](https://suttacentral.net/an5.38/en/sujato) when he said:

> “Mendicants, a faithful gentleman gets five benefits. What five?
> The good persons in the world show compassion first to the faithful, not so much to the unfaithful. They first approach the
> faithful, not so much the unfaithful. They first receive alms from
> the faithful, not so much the unfaithful. They first teach Dhamma
> to the faithful, not so much the unfaithful. **When their body breaks
> up, after death, the faithful are reborn in a good place, a heavenly
> realm.** A faithful gentleman gets these five benefits.

Emphasis mine.

I am trying to discern what this means with reference to the answers for the word upapajjati in [this question](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/29355/what-is-the-meaning-of-uppajjati-versus-upapajjati) which discussed the meaning of the word which is being translated here. Also, what did the Buddha mean when referring to the "break up of the body, after death" and has that been correctly translated?

Comment: I note that your question is tagged "theravada" and Gabe's answer is appropriate to that point of view. But as you no doubt know, the Theravadan view isn't the only way of looking at what the Buddha taught. More specifically, since Sanskrit scholar Joanna Jurewicz has been working to decode early teachings in Vedism, a fresh look at the way the Buddha taught, as derived from the early Vedic style, makes for a slightly different understanding of what he taught. If your interest is only in the Theravadan take on his teachings, this may not be of any interest to you.

Comment: Hello Linda, I am happy to have informed answers even if they do not come from an active Theravada practitioner, but I am mostly interested in answers from practicing Buddhists of *some* tradition. That said, if there is an interesting academic answer here that would inform Buddhist practice that would be welcome.

Comment: Traditions start somewhere. Do you consider Secular Buddhism to have enough gravitas to provide an answer? I've been a practicing Buddhist for over 30 years, and the answer I'd offer has had aspects published in the Journal of Oxford Buddhist Studies under the editorship of Professor Gombrich.

Comment: By all means go ahead :)

Comment: Thanks, Yeshe Tenley, I will. My first attempt first became a detailed short story, then a novella, then a novel, and was heading for trilogy when I thought better of it. I am now working on a different take that should be shorter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the Pali words on [Sutta Central](https://suttacentral.net/an5.38/pli/ms):

> ...  saddho kāyassa bhedā paraṁ maraṇā sugatiṁ saggaṁ lokaṁ upapajjati ...

To answer your question, I think the text has been correctly translated. The translated word “breaks”  corresponds to "bhedā". For this context see notes [from the PTS](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/bheda#pali):

> "Abl. bhedā after the destruction or dissolution in phrase kāyassa bhedā param maraṇā, i.e. after the breaking up of the body & after death: see kāya I. e. & cp. D. III, 52, 146 sq. , 258; Dh. 140; Pug. 51"

The other words roughly correspond to paraṁ=after, maraṇā=death, sugatiṃ=good (destination), saggaṃ and lokaṃ can be taken indepently but together they roughly translation to "heavenly region", upapajjati=reborn.

Again see notes for uppajjati in relation to saggaṁ and lokaṁ:

> Upapajjati, (doubtful whether a legitimate form as upa + pad or a diaeretic form of uppajjati = ud + pad. In this case all passages ought to go under the latter. Trenckner however (Notes 77) defends upa° & considers in many cases upp° a substitution for upa. The diaeresis may be due to metre, as nearly all forms are found in poetry. The v. l. upp° is apparently frequent; but it is almost impossible to distinguish between upap° and upp° in the Sinhalese writing, and either the scribe or the reader may mistake one for the other) to get to, be reborn in (Acc.); to originate, rise Vin. III, 20 (nirayaṃ); A. III, 415; V, 292 sq.; Sn. 584; It. 13 (nirayaṃ), 14 (sugatiṃ; v. l. upp°), 67 (saggaṃ lokaṃ; v. l. upp°); ...
> [PTS](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/upapajjati#pali)

A similar verse occurs in the Dhammapada:

> atha vassa agarani aggi dahati pavako
> kayassa bheda duppabbo nirayaj so 'papajjati
> (DhP 140)
> ...
> bheda: bheda-, N.m.: breaking, disunion. Abl.Sg. = bheda.
> The phrase kayassa bheda- ("disunion of the body") means "death" in the Pali texts. 
> [source](http://buddhism.lib.ntu.edu.tw/BDLM/en/lesson/pali/reading/gatha140.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Your question has two parts: What did the Buddha mean, and is the phrase "breakup of the body, after death" correctly translated. It seems clear that the latter is correct, and a defense of a positive answer has already been given by Gabe, so I won't address that.

"What did the Buddha mean" can only be a matter of opinion, since none of us is able to directly hear his thinking or ask him, but it is possible to look at the sutta for some answers, and consider the larger context of his talks in other suttas, to try to understand why he says what he says in AN 5.38.

What I notice about AN 5.38 is that

1. We aren't told who is speaking, but we might well assume it's the
   Buddha.
2. The talk is not a deep one as would be given to long-time monastics,
   and it is not being given to the clansmen (using Bodhi's translation
   of *kulaputta*).
3. Four of the five points address what benefits accrue to the
   clansmen.
4. The point that doesn't follow the main pattern seems to be
   addressing a benefit to the monastics, not to the "clansmen endowed
   with faith". It is that the monastics get alms from a person of
   faith.

Assuming it's the Buddha speaking, it's worth noting that it's not a deep dharma talk illuminating the finer points of his teaching. It appears to be a talk about why regular folk ("clansmen") who have faith are wise to have faith, and as such it would be addressed to new monastics, not long-time, experienced monks. One needs to question why the Buddha would be instructing inexperienced monks on the reasons the faith of clansmen is beneficial. That one of the five points he lists is of benefit to the monks might then give us a clue -- why should the monastics be kind to faithful clansmen? for alms!

Why then are these monks being told what benefit faith has for the clansmen? What do monastics do to gain alms from clansmen? They offer teachings. What teaching might novice monastics give to clansmen? How about a talk on why their faith is of benefit to them: It's because, dear clansmen, you'll get compassion from others, you'll get such a good reputation people will come to you, you'll get taught dhamma before anyone without faith does, you'll get a good rebirth, and (monastic holds out his bowl), you're known to be generous.

It is worth noting that when the Buddha speaks to individuals he encounters (not speaking of his devoted monastics here), he speaks to them addressing their concerns and without making dogmatic statements about what they should believe. He often enough points out the obvious consequences of what they believe, but he doesn't, for example, go around telling people they are just wrong to think that behaving like a dog will get them reborn as a dog in dog heaven, or even that there is no "self" -- he never says that. But he does point out the ways the behavior their thinking inspires in them leads to trouble, or that there is no discernible self to be found that matches what determined a "self" in their times -- that it was a separate thing, eternal, changeless. What he does do is address an individual's concern from within that individual's own worldview, pointing out any obvious flaws in the consequences of their thinking. He takes pains not to argue. He even says this.

In MN 18.4 he says, "Friend, I assert and proclaim [my teaching] in such a way that one does not quarrel with anyone in the world with its gods, its Maras, and its Brahmas, in this generation with its recluses and brahmins, its princes and its people; in such a way that perceptions no more underlie that brahmin who abides detached from sensual pleasures, without perplexity, shorn of worry, free from craving for any kind of being." SN 22.94 opens with "Bhikkhus, I do not dispute with the world; rather it is the world that disputes with me."

It seems apparent, to me at least, that in this sutta he is giving his monastics directions to go out and do what he does: give a teaching that fits within their worldview as to the reasons faith is worthwhile. Their worldview includes the belief that good behavior in this life leads to a better rebirth. If the world works the way they think it does, then this, too, would be a benefit of their faith. That doesn't mean the Buddha is sure that rebirth is the cosmic order. Even if he did, he would not say so because he'd be quoted on that and that would lead to 'proclaiming his teaching in such a way that he quarrels with the world'.

I do note that there are places in the suttas where he does seem to suggest that he has had direct experiences of his past lives. Why he does that would be part of a much larger, longer discussion. I further note that he sometimes tells people where their loved ones will be reborn after death. He himself answers why he does this, in MN 68.8-9.

> "What do you think, Anuruddha? What purpose does the Tathagata see
> that when a disciple has died, he declares his reappearance thus:
> 'So-and-so has reappeared in such-and-such a place...'?"
>
> "Anuruddha, it is not for the purpose of scheming to deceive people or
> for the purpose of flattering people or for the purpose of gain,
> honour, or renown, or with the thought, 'Let people know me to be
> thus,' that when a disciple has died, the Tathagata declares his
> reappearance... Rather, it is because there are faithful clansmen
> inspired and gladdened by what is lofty, who when they hear that,
> direct their minds to such a state, and that leads to their welfare
> and happiness for a long time."

Comment: "That doesn't mean the Buddha is sure that rebirth is the cosmic order."  If you read MN 60, you'll see that he was actually sure of it.

Comment: @Danilo: Two noteworthy points about it: 1. it is the only place in all the suttas that the Buddha makes such a dogmatic statement, which makes it suspect on that point alone. 2. As Thanissaro Bhikkhu notes in his own subtle way in his translation of that sutta, the statement I'm calling the lone dogmatic one breaks the logic of the sutta by not being safe bet arguments. He says "It is noteworthy that the arguments in A2 and B2 are not safe-bet arguments, for they assume that A is wrong and B is right. Whether these arguments date from the Buddha or were added at a later date, no one knows."

Comment: I would argue that one lone dogmatic statement is not to be trusted as the Buddha's words, especially when it breaks the logic of the sutta -- he is much better at constructing arguments than that. It shows the fingerprints of a less-bright, later interloper.

Comment: That reads as very special pleading. Regarding sutta that contradict your position as inauthentic - simply because it contradicts your position - is not convincing.

Comment: @Yeshe Tenley. I didn't judge it as inauthentic "simply because it contradicts my position." I did so for the two reasons listed.

Comment: @YesheTenley Those arguments (i.e. "this is the only sutta where that's said", and, "that doesn't fit within the logic of this sutta") were among the arguments detailed in the paper which was referenced in [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/3336/254). That was a different topic entirely, but it shows that is a kind of argument which some modern scholars make, or a kind of argument available to scholars, to assess whether a element of doctrine might be original or perhaps added at some later date.

Comment: Ok. However, I think we should be humble and hesitant to deem suttas as inauthentic because it doesn't fit with our pre-conceived narratives. The western world often comes at the Dharma with biases and in a very arrogant way tries to retrofit the Dharma and the Buddha into storylines that make it easier for the westerner to digest.  They like to hold on to the conceit that they know better about how the world works than some thousands of year old Indian ascetics. BTW, I am a westerner and I recognize this in myself as well.

Comment: I remember vividly arguing with my Teacher (who is from Tibet) trying to explain Einstein's special theory of relativity while he gently laughed at me. I insisted that Einstein had made a great advance and showed how time and the speed of light are intimately related. He replied and pointed out that *if* that is true, is is very good but only conventionally true and I shouldn't get hung up on it. This made me annoyed thinking that this simple monk just couldn't understand a sophisticated western idea and appreciate it. Only much later did I realize how wrong I was.

Comment: FWIW, I do think this answer is the best one after Gabe's. This one is at least honest in admission about what the Buddha did teach and not a completely tortured reading of words, but it still reminds me of my own arrogance towards my Teacher.

Comment: @Linda Blanchard, Iti 70-71, MN 130 and MN 143 are a few other examples where you can see that he was actually sure of it. I also see another major misconception in your post when you assume that the monks were instructed to be kind in order to gain almsfood (check AN 5:159 and Ud 6:2)

Comment: @Danillo. Sorry, my rather dry humor often gets taken as me being literal -- I was partially kidding about the monks. As for the Buddha's many, many references to having seen beings rearising and passing on according to their actions, note my comment under the OP about writing a trilogy. The understanding I am working with has so much evidence for it that when I just discuss one aspect folks think I'm ignorant of the whole of the Buddha's work, or I'm cherry-picking. I am not.

Comment: Summary of  Trilogy: The Buddha uses the structure he built in Dependent Arising (DA) to create a lesson he could use throughout his teachings and interactions with others to describe via metaphor -- or something like a metaphor but too huge to fit in that word -- how and why we end up causing ourselves to suffer. On the surface DA looks like it is about the cycle of rebirth. It is not. When he talks about "rising and passing away" he is talking about DA.

Comment: @LindaBlanchard , These are some other important suttas: Iti 24 and SN 15:3

Comment: @Yeshe Tenley, re your comment about arrogance: duly noted. It is understandable, given that you don't know me, that you would assume I had pre-conceived ideas of what the Buddha taught,  that I would cherry-pick to make what I read fit those ideas. But the actual case is that I came to reading the suttas with only questions, no fixed expectations. I began from wanting there to be perfect support for the Theravadan view of the teachings. I was surprised that wasn't what I found.

Comment: @Yeshe Tenley: As for arrogance, I wonder if it is not arrogant to assume that any of the traditions have an undistorted understanding of what the Buddha taught. It seems to me a humble-enough approach, to come to the texts with an open and empty mind, to let them reveal what they say, and to test it with personal practice. My teacher is the Buddha of the oldest texts, and I am certainly humble before him. In fact, in awe.

Comment: Not sure if that would be arrogant, but I think it wouldn't be cautious. However, rebirth has been a prominent feature of discussion since the earliest records we have of what the Buddha taught. See Questions of (King) Milinda and such. In addition, every extent tradition agrees that the Buddha did in fact acknowledge rebirth. He did not rebut it.  I'd also note that the sutta in question in this OP and your answer to it does not have anything to do with DA by your own account.

Comment: As I've stated before, I was initially very skeptical about rebirth and had a very hard time understanding how to fit it to my earlier understanding of emptiness and anatman. Nevertheless, I was hesitant enough to not write it off but keep working at it as my teacher suggested. I'm very grateful and profoundly happy that I did so, because far from contradicting rebirth my now understanding of emptiness *requires* rebirth or at least requires the non-aggressive denial of it as a conventional truth. IOW, finally understanding rebirth helped inform my understanding of emptiness.

Comment: Denying the conventional truth of rebirth to me is akin to an illusory dreamer vehemently asserting that upon waking from the dream nothing whatsoever can subsequently be experienced. That the dreamer waking from the dream is tantamount to a complete annihilation of the world and all experience foreclosing any future world or experience.

Comment: Denying rebirth is akin to Ven. Yamaka saying "As I understand the Teaching explained by the Blessed One, a monk with no more (mental) effluents, on the break-up of the body, is annihilated, perishes, & does not exist after death." and this was rebuked precisely because it presupposes the true and reliable existence of the monk in the here and now where no such true reliable existence can be found.

Comment: To deny rebirth is to reify the self in the here and now.

Comment: I don't deny rebirth.

Answer (score 2):

"Death" ("marana") does not happen to a Buddha (SN 22.85; MN 140; Dhp 21; etc ). The suttas say:

> Heedfulness is the path to the Deathless. Heedlessness is the path to
> death. The heedful die not. The heedless are as if dead already.
>
> Dhp 21

Therefore, the word "death" ("marana") does not mean "physical death" or the "ending of life". In the suttas, the Noble Ones refer to the ending of life as "kālakiriyā" ('completion of time'). "Death" means the death of "a being" (SN 12.2). "A being" is a "self-view" (SN 5.10) or "strong attachment" (SN 23.2).

The word "body" ("kaya") means "collection" of "five aggregates" forming a "self-identity" ("sakkaya") that is the composition of an act of kamma or becoming - refer to MN 44.

The words "sugati" and "sagga" mean "a happy state" in a "happy place". It may not literally mean a heaven in the clouds or on another planet. For example, in SN 35.135, it is said:

> You’re fortunate, mendicants, so very fortunate, to have the
> opportunity to lead the spiritual life.
>
> I’ve seen the heaven (saggā) called ‘the six fields of contact’.
> There, whatever you experience is likable, not unlikable; desirable,
> not undesirable; pleasant, not unpleasant.
>
> SN 35.135

Therefore, the  meaning of AN 5.38 is: "*When the collection of aggregates immersed in faith breaks up, after the death of the self-view of the faithful mind (which can have a temporary fear arise, which is why it is called 'death'), the faithful are reborn in a good place, a heavenly realm, such as in a state of clear light mind samadhi*".

But they are not yet an Arahant, which is why "after death" occurs. Therefore, AN 5.38 later says:

> They teach them the Dhamma, that dispels all suffering.  Understanding this teaching, they’re extinguished without defilements.”

AN 5.38 does not say they teach them "rebirth" because "rebirth" cannot dispel all suffering.

Answer (score 1):

In the Western, Christian world we teach young children that 'Santa Claus' watches over everyone, rewarding good children with presents on Christmas day, and punishing bad children with lumps of coal (and interestingly, no child ever seems to be punished; there are always presents under the tree in the morning...). Say what you like about it, good or bad, but it is what children can *understand* at their level. Children must grow into more sophisticated moral understandings.

If we read the remainder of the discourse, we find that the faithful person (the good person) becomes a refuge for 'monks, nuns, laywomen, and laymen', the way a great banyan tree at a crossroads becomes a refuge for birds and animals. What each needs it receives: those that need shade find shade; those that need fruit find fruit. And most importantly, these faithful people draw in the liberated, the wise, the undefiled: people who find in their faith and goodness a ripe field for planting the dharma. And then when the faithful person learns the dharma — grows and understands — she is "extinguished without defilements".

What happens to a tree when it falls and breaks apart? It has spread its seed; it has prepared the ground with its own life; a new tree rises in its place to fill its place. Is there more to ask than that? People need more reassurance than a tree, though, at least until they understand.

Comment: Are you equating this sutta to the Buddha instructing monks to preach the equivalent of Santa Claus? That poor Indian people are like children in their understanding?

Comment: @YesheTenley: Every person is like a child in the greater world: caught in fantasies and beliefs, asking endless curious questions, strutting over every success and crying over every failure.... Dukkha and tanhā are child's games that we've forgotten belong in the world of children. When we realize that, we can start to put them aside.

Comment: I agree for the most part. It's just that denying the conventional truth of rebirth - the western conceit - is the more childish and acknowledging it as the Buddha attested the more mature.

Comment: @YesheTenley: It isn't my intent to confirm or deny the facticity of rebirth, and I don't believe I did that in what I wrote. But the *concept* of rebirth... Well, that's a mental construct as subject to attachments and misperceptions as any other mental construct. If we grant that the Buddha attested to it, must we also grant that we (much less novices and laity) understand precisely what he was pointing at?

Comment: @YesheTenley: Whatever the facts of the matter — and whatever we choose to hold as true — the path is the same. All that changes is our expectations.

Comment: All very true and wise words @Ted Wrigley